Probabilistic interpretation of integer linearization solutions
Can we generate approximate integer/binary solutions using pure linear programming?
Suppose that I want to assign $resource_{i}$ to $team_1$ else $team_2$. A solution matrix, M of shape [i,2] could accomplish this where $ \Sigma_{j=1}^{2} M_{i,j} =1 \forall i \in I$.
However, suppose I could accept some degradation to to pure integer solutions; perhaps I could treat solutions as probabilistic where a row might equal $[0.9, 0.1]$ meaning there's a 90% chance that this item is assigned to team 1 (10% chance to team 2.)
I believe I could accomplish this as follows:

$x_i \le M_{i,j} \quad \forall j \in {1,2} \quad \forall i \in I$
$y_i \ge M_{i,j} \quad \forall j \in {1,2} \quad \forall i \in I$
$d_i \le y_i - x_i \forall i \in I$
$ max(\Sigma_{i=1}^{I} d_i)$
Subject to constraints...

I believe that this routine should ensure that values in M are close to ${1,0}$ without preference for either team. I might even be able to adopt a multi-stage model where in the first stage, I dispense with integer programming all together and maximize (or minimize) some objective of interest. Then in the second stage, constrain that this target objective is reached (subject to some relaxation/target discount factor) while the explicit objective is to assign resources to teams in a manner that approximates integer programming.
I'm curious if this approach is common? And if there are any pitfalls that I should be aware of?
Edit:
In lieu of Prubin's comment, I've rewritten formulation changes affect bullets [3&4]. In [3], I introduce "upper tightness" as $2y_i - \Sigma_{j=1}^{2}M_{i,j}$ for any given j.
Suppose that M[i,:] = [0.1, 0.9] and y=0.91. The upper tightness is 0.91*2 - 1 = 0.82.   But I also constrain that the lower tightness equal 0.82, where 1-0.82 = 0.18 = 0.09*2. So if $y_i=0.91$ then $x_i = 0.09$.
Constraint [3] ensures that upper and lower tightness are symmetric around the interval M[i,:]. Whereas in [4] the objective effectively maximizes upper tightness.
If left as is, the solver would converge on M[i,:]=[0.5, 0.5] hence constraints in [5] from a previous stage solution.

$x_i \le M_{i,j} \quad \forall j \in {1,2} \quad \forall i \in I$
$y_i \ge M_{i,j} \quad \forall j \in {1,2} \quad \forall i \in I$
$2y_i - \Sigma_{j=1}^{2} M_{i,j} = \Sigma_{j=1}^{2} M_{i,j} - 2x_i \quad \forall i \in I$
$ min(\Sigma_{i=1}^{I} 2y_i - \Sigma_{j=1}^{2} M_{i,j})$
Subject to constraints...


Search for "relax-and-fix heuristic" and "randomized rounding"

I'll assume the $x$ and $y$ variables have domain $[0,1].$ If the constraints only involve the $M$ variables, then what stops the solver from setting $x_i =0,$ $y_i=1$ and $d_i = 1$ (which optimizes objective (4)) regardless of the $M$ values?

@prubin - great insight; I've edited and think this alternative is feasible.
